# Objective-C, Calculating NSTimeInterval correctly?

Tags: objective-c, macos, nstimer, nstimeinterval

I'm trying to calculate (in milliseconds) how much time went by while completing operations in my app. I've read through most of the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) and looked through examples, although my app seems to crash near the NSLog function. All of the answers addressed here seem to be specifically for iOS, and I'm trying to get this working with OSX. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated — thank you.

```
- (void)someMethod {

    NSTimeInterval startTime = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];

    // Do something else
    // Now see how much time went by

    NSTimeInterval endTime = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];

    double elapsedTime = startTime - endTime;

    NSLog(@"time: %@", elapsedTime);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to print an object with `%@` but the time is a double. Instead you should change the last line to

```
NSLog(@"time: %f", elapsedTime);
```

Also note that `startTime - endTime` give you a negative time so you should probably switch the order to get the correct duration.

Comment: Thank you — I thought that's what the problem might have been; is there a good way to format the output so it's more readable? It currently looks like: `time: -0.039568`, so I'd like it more like `time: 3 ms`.

Comment: You can so something like (@"Time: %.2f ms", elapsedTime * 1000.0).

Answer (score 3):

An alternative way to do it would be to grab the start NSDate. Then to find time elapsed, call `[startDate timeIntervalSinceNow]`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the alternate method; is there any advantage or difference in doing it this way?

Comment: It is less code and I just think it looks cleaner, and more semantically represents what you are doing: You want the elapsed time between one moment and another, you don't really want to be worrying about "reference dates".